# LLVM: PHINode should have one entry per predecessor error despite having enough edges

Tags: llvm

I'm working on some LLVM optimizations and am receiving the following error:

```
PHINode should have one entry for each predecessor of its parent basic block!
  %z1 = phi i32 [ 6, %then ], [ 3, %entry ]
```

Despite the block only having 2 predecessors.
The function in IR looks like this before my optimization:

```
entry:
  %x = alloca i32, align 4
  %y = alloca i32, align 4
  %z = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 1, ptr %x, align 4
  store i32 2, ptr %y, align 4
  store i32 3, ptr %z, align 4
  %0 = load i32, ptr %x, align 4
  %1 = load i32, ptr %y, align 4
  %2 = icmp slt i32 %0, %1
  br i1 %2, label %then, label %after

then:                                             ; preds = %entry
  store i32 6, ptr %z, align 4
  br label %after

after:                                            ; preds = %then, %entry
  %3 = load i32, ptr %z, align 4
  ret i32 %3
```

So `after` has 2 predecessors both of which are shown in the phi node.

In fact, in my code I have `assert(phi->isComplete())` and this does not error. I set the number of edges for the phi node with `pred_size(bb)` of the basic block that contains this phi. I printed that value out and it indeed printed 2.

I add edges as

```
for (BasicBlock *pred : predecessors(&bb)) {

    phi->addIncoming(this->Post[pred][alloca], pred);
}
assert (phi->isComplete());
```

so this should have all the predecesor blocks accounted for. Does anyone have ideas for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out why. LLVM requires that phi instructions be at the front of a basic block (https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#phi-instruction) but I was not always placing them there.

This error message was misleading. When I called `PHINode::Create` I now need to pass in the `->Front()` of the basic block I am working on and the error is removed.